# Как получить кадр (скриншот) видеофайла ? (c#)

Tags: c#

Хотя бы примерно куда копать

Comment: там вроде только wmv, а как быть если надо avi или видео с другим расширением ?

Comment: @plus_1_corporation, ну поглядите другие либы. Навскидку приходит на ум AForge.NET

Comment: из c# можно вызвать ffmpeg с помощью Process. и в него передать параметры. пример параметров для ffmpeg -- [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18539500)

Answer (score 3):

Используйте, например, [AsfMojo](http://asfmojo.codeplex.com/)

```
string videoFile = путь_к_файлу;
Bitmap bitmap = AsfImage.FromFile(videoFile).AtOffset(время);
```