# Получение отображаемого изображения в PictureBox WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Работаю над программой для распознавания номеров с потокового видео (IP камер).
Камеры используются фирмы Hikvision, соответственно для получения видео с камеры используется SDK (думаю, для решения вопроса версия не важна).

Есть метод `int NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(int iUserID, ref NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO lpPreviewInfo, REALDATACALLBACK fRealDataCallBack_V30, IntPtr pUser)` где:

- iUserID - ИД залогиненого на камере пользователя,
- NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO - структура с параметрами,
- REALDATACALLBACK fRealDataCallBack_V30 - не используется, IntPtr pUser - не понятно что нужно туда передавать. У меня передается IntPtr.Zero

Сама структура:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO
{
        public Int32 lChannel; // Номер канала
        public uint dwStreamType; // тип потока , 0-основной поток, 1 - суб поток, 2 - суб поток , 3 - суб поток.
        public uint dwLinkMode; // 0: TCP, 1: UDP, 2: MULTICAST, 3 - RTP, 4-RTP/RTSP, 5 - RSTP/HTTP
        public IntPtr hPlayWnd; //"HCNetSDK.dll" хендл окна воспроизведения, NULL означает, что изображение не воспроизводится
        public bool bBlocked; // 0-неблокирующий доступ, 1-блокирующий доступ. Если блокируется отказ внутреннего подключения SDK, будет возвращен 5 секунд для возврата, что не подходит для опроса.
        public bool bPassbackRecord; //"HCNetSDK.dll" 0 - не включать воспроизведение видео, 1 - включить воспроизведение видео
        public byte byPreviewMode; // Режим предварительного просмотра, 0-нормальный просмотр, 1 предварительный просмотр с задержкой
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = STREAM_ID_LEN, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public byte[] byStreamID; // Этот идентификатор включен, когда lChannel равен 0xffffffff
        public byte byProtoType; // протокол прикладного уровня, 0 - частный протокол, протокол 1-RTSP
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 222, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1)]
        public byte[] byRes;
 }
```

Медленно подходим к сути вопроса.

В коде, старт воспроизведения выглядит так (это вырезка из метода) :

```
CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO lpPreviewInfo = new CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_PREVIEWINFO();
lpPreviewInfo.hPlayWnd = Handle; //Handle - хендл PictureBox с формы, передаваемый в метод через аргумент
lpPreviewInfo.dwStreamType = 1;
pPreviewInfo.dwLinkMode = 0;
lpPreviewInfo.bBlocked = true;

//Start live view 
m_lRealHandle = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_RealPlay_V40(m_lUserID, ref lpPreviewInfo, null/*RealData*/, IntPtr.Zero);
```

После выполнения метода в PictureBox'е на форме начинает транслироваться видео.
Да, это все еще предыстория, c отображением видео у меня все в порядке.

С этого видео транслируемого на форму мне нужно распознать ГРН ТС (номер машины). Для распознавания используется библиотека от компании OOO "MegaPixel" (MPixel) она платная, но не суть. Ознакомился с описанием, разобрался что да как там. Проинициализировал SDK, задал параметры канала, задал параметры распознавания и т.д. Далее нужно использовать метод поиска зон с гос. номерами `Int32 CFCHRun(int Channel, IntPtr imgbuf, Int32 flag);` 
В этот метод 2-ым параметром нужно передать указатель на контрол в котором идет отображение видео. При указании хендла моего PictureBox этот метод ничего не находит в нем. Cвойство image у моего PictureBox пустое.

```
Bitmap savedBit = new Bitmap(RealPlayWnds.Width, RealPlayWnds.Height);
RealPlayWnds.DrawToBitmap(savedBit, RealPlayWnds.ClientRectangle);
savedBit.Save(@"D:\123.bmp");
```

Так тоже ничего не сохраняет, точнее сохраняет, но картинка чисто черная.

Вот и встает вопрос, как мне получить картинку из моего PictureBox и отдать далее на обработку? Я так понял, SDK от камеры использует Native API и каким-то образом рисует потом уже картинку на своих оверлеях.

Comment: Чтобы дочитать это до конца потребовалось нечеловеческое напряжение воли. Мне кажется, что люди займутся Вашей проблемой, лишь после того, как будет убрано все лишние, не имеющие отношения к сути проблемы

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я специально постарался максимально широко расписать процесс работы ПО, чтобы люди могли иметь представление о том откуда ноги растут.

Comment: почему вы `imgbuf` считаете не сокращением от `image buffer` (непосредственно изображение), а именно > _контрол_ _в_ _котором_ _идет_ _отображение_ _видео_?? ни одного общего слова о_О

Comment: скачал и посмотрел их сэмпл для C# (CarPlateToolsCS.zip) -- вторым параметром передаётся указатель на изображение отдельного кадра (буфер, именно область памяти) в формате описания пикселов GRAY / UYVY / YUY2 / Y411 / RGB / JPEG

Comment: `RealPlayWnds` это что? не нашёл такого в сэмпле SDK  =(

Comment: RealPlayWnds это мой PictureBox. Я понимаю что он требует от меня. Я не могу из моего PictureBox дёрнуть картинку и переконвертировать в требуемый для библиотеки распознавания вид

Answer (score 1):

Пока написал костыль через метод GetPucture_NEW из SDK камеры, который возвращает картинку с камеры в виде массива байт. Но считаю, что это не очень правильно.

Может все-таки кто-то сталкивался с описанной мной выше проблемой ?

```
CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_JPEGPARA lpJpegPara = new CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_JPEGPARA();
lpJpegPara.wPicQuality = 0; 
lpJpegPara.wPicSize = 0xff; 

byJpegPicBuffer = new byte[iBuffSize];
if (!CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_CaptureJPEGPicture_NEW(m_lUserID, 1, ref lpJpegPara, byJpegPicBuffer, iBuffSize, ref dwSizeReturned))
{
    iLastErr = CHCNetSDK.NET_DVR_GetLastError();
    str = "NET_DVR_CaptureJPEGPicture_NEW failed, error code= " + iLastErr;
}
else
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    int iLen = (int)dwSizeReturned;
    ms.Write(byJpegPicBuffer, 0, iLen);
    Bitmap dmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    pictureBox1.Image = dmp;
    ms.Close();

    IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(byJpegPicBuffer.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(byJpegPicBuffer, 0, unmanagedPointer, byJpegPicBuffer.Length);
    var qwe = megalib.CFCHRun(1, unmanagedPointer, megalib.RUN_FIELD);
    CountZone.Text = qwe.ToString();
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPointer);
}
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более описание вашего "костыля".

Comment: Это не костыль, а наоборот правильный подход. Костылем было бы вытягивание изображения из контекста устройства через BitBlt (которое бы ломалось при перемещении окна на задний план).

Comment: @0xdb Держи. Изменил свой ответ

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight . Сейчас поясню почему костыль. У меня в приложении и так  идет Live Stream  с камеры(т.е я и так по факту получаю эти кадры), но т.к SDK их само обрабатывает и кладет на оверлеи свои, я не могу получить к ним доступ. Следственно идет получение Live и параллельно с ним я дергаю другим методом опять с камеры картинку. Так же дергать Snapshot с камеры несколько раз в секунду не лучшая затея я считаю. Но мне нужно это делать чтобы отдать на обработку распознаванию несколько изображений .

Answer (score 0):

1. Почему именно PictureBox, пробовали использовать другой контрол?
2. Aforge рассматривали? Очень удобно работает, как с потоковым видео, так и с http-потоком.

Так же [посмотрите сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275516/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-c)

Comment: 1 - Пробовал, без разницы какой контрол) Будь-то PictureBox,Panel, Button,Label ))
2 - Насколько мне известно Aforge не работает с RTSP потоками
3 - По ссылке. Это разбор уже готового видео как я понял. Для меня сохранять постоянно поток на диск, а потом его разбирать и удалять не вариант.